# Silent letters in Italian

Tags: letters

Which letters in which situations are silent?  I read [Italian orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_orthography) article but it does not complete (for example it does not mention [silent i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_letter#Italian)).

Comment: I know it's what's written on Wikipedia, but I wouldn't call it a "silent i", unless you think that the h in chat is silent too. It does modify the pronunciation of the surrounding letter.

Comment: I'd take everything I read on Wikipedia with a grain of salt. A silent letter (in Italian, *muta*) is one that is effectively not pronounced, as *h* in *hanno*, or *i* in *cieco*. As Denis says, one that modifies the sound of another letter (as the *i* in *giacca*) isn't silent.

Comment: And it is also false to say that in Italian *h* is always silent: think about *ce* versus *che*.

Comment: We have a different definition of 'silent' -- by my one, the `h` in `che` and the `i` in `cieco` are silent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the word *giorno* the letter *i* has essentially the same role as the *h* in *che*. We don't “pronounce” the *i*, which just denotes using the palatal sound for *g* like in *gesto*: /ʤ/. You can call it “silent”, if you wish, but its role is just “orthographic“: it's like a diacritic, but it's written next to the letter it modifies. Anyway, a silent letter seems to be one that stands for no sound, in Italian only *h*.

Depending on the speaker, the realization of the phoneme /ʤ/ can vary, but there is definitely no diphthong involved.

<sub>There is also no diphthong in *già* and *giù*; they are written with an accent for orthographic uniformity with *più* and *piè*, where a diphthong exists. A similar case is *ciò*.</sub>

This “orthographic i” is used after *c* or *g* to denote the palatal sound when followed by *a*, *o* or *u*:

> ciabatta, rancio, ciuffo, giacca, giorno, giusto

Conversely, the “orthographic h” is used to denote the “hard“ sound when *c* or *g* are followed by *e* or *i*:

> chela, china, alghe, fanghi

<sub>The *i* in *cieco* has a different nature: it's not pronounced in most of Italy, but it is (at least weakly) where the phenomenon of [*mobile diphthong*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dittongo_mobile) is still alive (for instance the region of Naples). The “rules” of the mobile diphthong requires it appears in *cieco* but not in *cecità*. Notwithstanding the fact that most Italians don't pronounce the diphthong in *cieco*, the orthography maintains it.</sub>

The *i* is also “orthographic” when the trigraph *gli* is followed by another vowel: *daglielo*.

Comment: egreg, are you sure that such *i*s and *h*s can actually be considered silent? If so, half the letters in English orthography should be considered such as well, while I believe the definition, both for English “silent” and Italian *muta*, is quite stricter, limited to cases such as “b” in “doubt” and “h” in *hanno*.

Comment: ...or “D” in “Django”.

Comment: @DaG I'd call it “diacritic”, maybe, or “orthographic”. Changed accordingly.